# How to factor a polynomial in real numbers?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Which of the following polynomials can't be factored in real numbers?
Multiple choice question from an old test.
Got the following polynomials:
$x^8$
$(x-3)(x^2+x+1)$
$(x-2)^3(x^2-1)$
$x^8(x^2-1)$
$(x^2-1)^3$
$x(x-1)(x+1)$

Solution:
Solving $x^2+x+1$ isnt possible with real numbers hence D is negative?
There for answer must be 
$(x-3)(x^2+x+1)$
Edited right answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "factor in real numbers"? If you mean "splits into real linear factors", then a lot of them satisfy that condition.

Comment: Oh sorry the question is which of them cannot be factored in real numbers. Hence my answer

Comment: Your choice seems to be wrong - $x^2+x+1$ cannot be factored, but you chose the third polynomial instead of the second polynomial.

Comment: You are right. It was exactly what i meant, just copied wrong polynomial when i had to do the last answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only polynomial in that list that doesn't split into linear factors is the one with $x^2 + x + 1$ because its discriminant is $-3$. For the other ones,

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
x^8 & = x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x \\
(x-2)^3 (x^2-1) & = (x-2)(x-2)(x-2)(x-1)(x+1) \\
(x^2-1)^3 &= (x-1)(x+1)(x-1)(x+1)(x-1)(x+1) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
and so on. By the way, the answer $(x-3)(x^2+x+1)$ cannot be factored over the reals, but it can be factored over $\mathbb C$, because the complex numbers have this property that every polynomial splits. As an example, 
$$
x^2 + x + 1 = \left( x - \frac{-1 + \sqrt 3 i}2 \right) \left( x - \frac{-1 - \sqrt 3 i}2 \right),
$$
where $i$ is defined so that $i^2 = -1$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks DaSilve. Nice with some additional info to my answer :)

Comment: @Alex : Please, don't screw up my name. =P And it was my pleasure.

Comment: Sorry Da Silva. Can u tell me how to tag people with a name like yours? I only figured how to do it with "connected" names.

Comment: I think @Patrick would do the trick, but I'm not quite sure. Anyway that's how I tag, see how I tagged you. Either way I got the notice because it's a comment on my answer, so it's okay.